# self.view set frame not work when keyboard show

Tags: ios, keyboard, resize, frame

I met a problem -- when the keyboard show, my code will set the view controller's view frame size so with the constraints setting, all the components will be in the correct position. However, sometimes it will work like the left picture, but if i enter this view controller from some specific points, it will look like the right side picture.

[image]

and here is my code when detect the keyboard show up..

```
- (void)moveTextViewForKeyboard:(NSNotification*)aNotification
                         up:(BOOL)up {

NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

if (up) {
    viewFrame.size.height = screenHeight - (keyboardFrame.size.height) - viewFrame.origin.y;
} else {
    viewFrame.size.height = screenHeight;
}

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

I've already searched here for days... still have no luck :(    is there expert who can help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using autolayout you should not set frame manually probably it won't change the inteface or is likely to mess your UI.
 Create a reference to one or more constraints, change their `constant` property to accommodate the keyboard change, then asks autolayout to update the layout by using `setNeedsLayout` and `-layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way in auto layout environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrea, it works as you said. i learn a lesson.  :)